# Who or what is 'our God' in Swinburne's 'Ave atque Vale'?

Tags: poetry, religion, myths, algernon-charles-swinburne

*The following is a bonus question to ["Who is the 'pale Titan-woman' in Swinburne's 'Ave atque Vale'?"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/25685/who-is-the-pale-titan-woman-in-swinburnes-ave-atque-vale), which I was advised to separate into its own question.*

The twelfth verse of **['Ave atque Vale'](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45275/ave-atque-vale-56d224b50fa53)** by **[Algernon Charles Swinburne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algernon_Charles_Swinburne)** reads:

> But by no hand nor any treason stricken,
> Not like the low-lying head of Him, the King,
> The flame that made of Troy a ruinous thing,
> Thou liest, and on this dust no tears could quicken
> There fall no tears like theirs that all men hear
> Fall tear by sweet imperishable tear
> Down the opening leaves of holy poets' pages.
> Thee not Orestes, not Electra mourns;
> But bending us-ward with memorial urns
> The most high Muses that fulfil all ages
> Weep, and **our God**'s heart yearns.

To whom does 'our God' refer? To the one God of monotheism and/or Christianity? The capitalisation seems to point in that direction; elsewhere, a lower case G is used; elsewhere, Swinburne refers to various gods, but here to God. But then again I know that Swinburne was not a Christian in any meaningful sense, but was in fact explicitly atheistic. But perhaps the poet was speaking as a representative of an era in which the polytheism of the classical world had been displaced by monotheism? I really do not know at this point!

Comment: Wouldn't that God be the same as the "God of all suns and songs," a few stanzas later? It seems to me that there are only two possible choices for this God: Apollo (God of the Sun, poetry, and presumably poets) or the Christian God (God of everything).

Comment: Well, as you said yourself, the 'God of all suns and songs' *could* be Apollo, but then Apollo doesn't fit at all as 'our God'. Perhaps 'our' could be made to fit in the sense that both Swinburne and Baudelaire were poets, and thus fell under Apollo's patronage. But why is Apollo God-with-a-capital-G, and not all the other deities referenced in this poem?

Comment: @user14111 Interesting. So you think that 'our God' could be either the Christian God or Apollo, but, short of digging up and reanimating Swinburne, it is impossible to come down on either with anything approaching certainty? Is that a fair summary of your position? If it is, and if you were to put that in an answer with your reasoning, I would accept it.

Comment: The references to Troy and Muses make me think it is not the Christian God.

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that the last line of staanza XII, along with stanzas XIII and XIV reference "our God", while stanza XV shifts to Aphrodite, introducing her with "And one weeps with him ..." is strong evidence that "our God" is Apollo. This makes sense if you take "our" as referring to Swinburne, Baudelaire, and other poets.

Comment: It's not completely clear that *God's* should be capitalized. In the book [*The British Poets, Vol. III — Keats to Morris*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Keats_to_Morris/Qh9sAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22Weep,%20and%20our%20God%27s%20heart%20yearns.%22) (1876), edited by Rossiter Johnson, *"god's"* is lowercase. Was this change intentional on Swinburne's part? I can't tell.